# Neo4j: Returning parallel query results

Tags: neo4j, cypher, match, graph-databases

To preface I am relatively new to `Neo4j/Cypher`. The query I am trying to write here will return all nodes that fulfill either: 
 **i)** first order interaction with a *named node* (f1-3); 
**OR**  
**ii)** exist within a path between two *named nodes*, with a maximum step of 3 nodes. Naturally I would also like to return the *named nodes*. The query I am currently using is shown below:

```
MATCH (que:Entity)-[:pp]-(con)-[:pp]-(con)-[:pp]-(que:Entity)
WHERE que.Symbol = "f1" OR que.Symbol = "f2" OR que.Symbol = "f3"
WITH que, con
MATCH (que:Protein)-[:pp]-(loc:Protein)
RETURN que, loc, con
```

The data in use has 1 node type and 1 relationship type. Within the proposed query I am using `que` to refer to *named nodes* and `Symbol` refers to a node attribute (string) used to refer to each *named node*, within the data set it is a common name. I am essentially looking to return the friends of each named individual along with all friends linking each named individual (with a maximum path length of two connecting friends). Basic diagram shown below; directionality of relationship is not important. To clarify I would like  to return **only** the coloured nodes.

[image: Illustration of desired result]

My apologies for any cringes induced by the simplicity of this question and any mistakes with my attempted query.

Comment: Hi Rob. Your question is a bit unclear... Can you provide more details? Maybe you should share a sample data set with the expected result. Thanks.

Comment: Rob, take a look in my answer. Let me know if it worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample table of results? I'm not quite sure how you want the output, given that you want many things returned from this (and your current example return of `que, loc, con` is going to get very messy, as you'd be returning cross products  of the nodes involved)

Comment: After some thought, it would probably be better to return the data in two tables (nodes and relationships independently). Is there a way to project the subgraph into a separate db for analysis?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand your question completely, but I think you can use a [variable-length path](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength) to achieve the goal.

```
MATCH (que:Entity)-[:pp*1..3]-(con)
WHERE que.Symbol in ['f1','f2','f3']
RETURN que, con
```

The above query is matching all path with minimum size of 1 (direct friends) and maximum size of 3.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thank you for the effort but this unfortunately doesn't answer the query entirely as it will also return 2nd order nodes which to not belong a connecting path between two _named nodes_. I have included a diagram above which may help to clarify the query.

Comment: @RobSellers Right. Maybe adding a constraint in the `WHERE` clause, like this: `MATCH p = (que:Entity)-[:pp*1..3]-(con)
WHERE size(p) in [1,3] and que.Symbol in ['f1','f2','f3']
RETURN que, con`

Comment: @RobSellers when you match a node between two named nodes you want to return the node and both named nodes, right?